# Texture edges are moving when camera is moved

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

The textures look good as long as the camera remains in a fixed position and rotation. However, when the camera is moving or rotating, (partial) lines appear between textures. I think it has to do something with subpixel correction. The texel is switching between the previous and the next one.

For my textures I use:

```
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
```

The same problem appears when using `GL_NEAREST`.

The fragment shader uses simple texture lookups:

`color = texture( textureID, UV );`

Or maybe this is an aliasing problem?

**Edit - image**

[image: Random lines appear and move between cubes when moving camera]

**Edit - UV image: same problem**

[image: UV]

**Edit Normals as colors**

It looks like the depth is not sorted well.

I am using perspective projection.

[image: Normals]

Comment: Have you tried aniso filtering and mipmapping?

Comment: I've tried `glGenerateMipmap`, but not sure if I used it correctly. What is aniso filtering?

Comment: Hard to tell from the question but try GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR as your min filter.

Comment: Updated question with clearer image!

Comment: @Robinson Same problem after trying your suggestion.

Comment: How do you draw those geometries?

Comment: Update: It's not the textures. It also appears when I draw the UV coordinates as in the image I added.

I draw the cubes per quad, in a loop using `glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 2 * 3 );`

Comment: Update: It seems that it's a depth problem. I added a new image with normals as colors and you can see the colors are different on the edges.

Comment: You draw the cubes ...? You should explain what is actually being drawn here in the question, because I looked at it and thought this was a texture spread across a flat plane. That is definitely primitive aliasing if it affects even the texture coordinates, but it ought to be cancelled out given your wrap mode. Is it possible that those stray lines are actually two or more improperly rendered cubes (does this happen if you only draw one cube)?

Comment: Is there any anti-aliasing or blending in the process ?

Comment: 1) There was a problem with rendering the cubes. The cubes are rendered per quad. I am now rendering all blocks per side of the quad. So first, all fronts, then all sides etc. There are no lines anymore, while displaying the normals as colors. However, I think there is still aliasing, and also between the textures there is one lines of pixels that switches texels on every edge of a cube. As you can see on my UV image. The problem in the third image is solved now. 2) I don't think there is anti aliasing.

Comment: PS: Only the bottom still shows some random pixels from the quad color of the quad which is rendered before. The bottom is rendered second last. The tops are rendered last.