# How to avoid pixelated geometry while using a moving camera with perspective view?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

**While I move the camera, the pixels of the geometry are moving as well.**

[image: Pixelated Geometry]

For perspective projection I use

```
glm::perspective( 45.0f, float( screenWidth ) / float( screenHeight ), 1.0f, 140.0f );
```

I draw the cubes per side.

This seems like an easy question. Should I set the resolution higher somewhere?

Comment: If you're targetting realtime render, you're gonna be bound with your screen resolution anyway. You might need anti-aliasing here.

Comment: I'd try using the GPU control panel first if it has such an option; simply force it for your binary and see if it improves anything. Programatically, you need an appropriate Pixel Format for your window, and then a call to `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB);`

Comment: isn't this the same issue as your previous http://stackoverflow.com/q/33087680/2564301?

Comment: @JongWare It is a bit different and also more concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bartek Banachewicz commented, enabling Anti Aliasing in OpenGL fixed the issue.

I am using MSAA for Anti Aliasing.

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more (decorate with a code snippet or a reference)